how can I get the result of openssl_public_decrypt?
The result is "Decrypted data is not a string", I don't know why
#include "php.h"
#include "ext/standard/info.h"
#include "ext/standard/php_string.h"
#include "ext/standard/base64.h"
PHP_FUNCTION(my_openssl_public_decrypt) {
    zend_string *data, *public_key;
    zval func_name;
    zval result;
    zval params[3];
    zval decrypted_zval;
    

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "SS", &data, &public_key) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    

    zend_string *raw_data=php_base64_decode_ex((const unsigned char*)(ZSTR_VAL(data)), ZSTR_LEN(data), 0);
    
    
    ZVAL_STR(&func_name, zend_string_init("openssl_public_decrypt",strlen("openssl_public_decrypt"),0));
    
    
    ZVAL_STR(&params[0],raw_data);
    ZVAL_NEW_REF(&params[1],&decrypted_zval);
    ZVAL_STR(&params[2],public_key);
   
    
    if (call_user_function(EG(function_table), NULL, &func_name, &result, 3, params) == FAILURE) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Failed to call openssl_public_decrypt");
        php_printf("%s","Failed to call openssl_public_decrypt\r\n");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
     
   
    if (Z_TYPE(result) == IS_TRUE) {
        if (Z_TYPE(decrypted_zval) == IS_STRING) {
            RETURN_TRUE;
            
        } else {
            php_printf("%s","Decrypted data is not a string\r\n");
            php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Decrypted data is not a string");
            RETURN_FALSE;
        }
    } else {
        php_printf("%s","Decryption failed\r\n");
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Decryption failed");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
}


We can't tell with the information given. It could be a boolean or a null. It's unlikely to be an object or an array, since openssl_private_encrypt can only encrypt strings.

It's all about how you're handling the decrypted data and verifying its type, try this code, I commented every part:
PHP_FUNCTION(my_openssl_public_decrypt) {
    zend_string *data, *public_key;
    zval func_name, result;
    zval params[3];
    zval decrypted_zval;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "SS", &data, &public_key) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    // Decode Base64
    zend_string *raw_data = php_base64_decode_ex((const unsigned char *)(ZSTR_VAL(data)), ZSTR_LEN(data), 0);
    if (!raw_data) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Failed to decode Base64 data");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    // Prepare parameters
    ZVAL_STR(&params[0], raw_data);
    ZVAL_NULL(&decrypted_zval);
    ZVAL_NEW_REF(&params[1], &decrypted_zval);
    ZVAL_STR(&params[2], public_key);

    // Call openssl_public_decrypt
    ZVAL_STR(&func_name, zend_string_init("openssl_public_decrypt", strlen("openssl_public_decrypt"), 0));
    if (call_user_function(EG(function_table), NULL, &func_name, &result, 3, params) == FAILURE) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Failed to call openssl_public_decrypt");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    // Check if decryption was successful
    if (Z_TYPE(result) != IS_TRUE) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "openssl_public_decrypt failed");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    // Verify decrypted data
    if (Z_TYPE_P(Z_REFVAL_P(&params[1])) != IS_STRING) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Decrypted data is not a string");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    // Return decrypted string
    RETVAL_STR(Z_STR_P(Z_REFVAL_P(&params[1])));
}


Thank you very much
